# Daily Spike on Azure PaaS CD Server

Tags: azure, paas

We have been facing daily spikes for PROD CD typically starting at 9 AM SGT and can last between half an hour to sometimes 11 AM+ SGT with instability and increased 5xx errors.

9 AM spike would be the most unstable and would sometimes render the site unresponsive or produce downtime.

So far, I have done the following:

1. Disabled WebJobs to see if this is causing spikes
2. Collected crash, memory dump, analyzed, and did tweaks (tweaked polling interval and timeouts, etc.)
3. Tuned Redis
4. Checked logs
5. Others

There is also no such high traffic on the website during this time.

I cannot identify what causes this daily spike which causes the site to be unstable.

Our Sitecore application is deployed on `Azure PaaS (Sitecore Managed Cloud Service)` and it's in `Sitecore version 10.2.1`.

Does anyone faced a similar kind of situation suggestion, please?

[image]

**Update:** As per Mark's suggestion, I have tried to collect the [Performance Profile](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0111669#CollectingAPerformanceProfile) but it's giving me an error:

[image]

Comment: Good to check this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15008/response-time-and-resource-usage-increase-during-4-hours

Comment: I'd say you'll need to collect a performance profile so you can see hotpath code and go from there.

Comment: I have tried it but I am not able to collect it due to some error. Thanks, I update the question with a performance profile error.